# Bound of the Minimum Eigenvalue of Product between Matrices

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-rank

We have two real-valued Positive Semi-definite matrices, $A$ and $B$, both $n$ by $n$.

Can the minimum eigenvalue $\lambda_\mathrm{min}(AB)$ be lower-bounded using the following eigenvalue sequences?

$\lambda_1(A)\ge \lambda_2(A) \dots \lambda_\mathrm{min}(A)$

$\lambda_1(B)\ge \lambda_2(B) \dots \lambda_\mathrm{min}(B)$

Not much are known other than PSDness of two matrices, except rank of $B$ is $n-1$.

Comment: The minimum eigenvalue is necessarily $0$.

Comment: If the rank is not full, it must have a non trivial kernel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The minimum eigenvalue is necessarily $0$. We can prove that this is the case as follows:

We begin by noting that the product $AB$ has non-negative eigenvalues.  We can see this by noting that if $A$ is invertible, then $AB$ is similar to the positive semidefinite matrix
$$
A^{1/2}BA^{1/2} = A^{-1/2}(AB)A^{1/2}
$$
If $A$ fails to be invertible, then it suffices to note that $AB = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+}(A+\epsilon I)B$.

Because $B$ is singular, the product $AB$ is singular.

So, $AB$ is a singular matrix with non-negative eigenvalues.  So, its minimum eigenvalue must be $0$.

Comment: Thanks for answering. simple and succinct.  However that makes me wondering if the following is also true: $B$ is singular, then $UBU^T$ is also singular, where $U$ is a full rank matrix.

Comment: Yep, that's also true, assuming all the matrices are square.

Comment: If $U$ is not square (in particular: if $U$ has more columns than rows), then the product could be non-singular.

Comment: Thanks again, however, before looking at your comment, I have just posted another question, with a little more details, just in case if you are interested in answering: [link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1332262/minimum-eigenvalue-of-uaut)

Comment: I see your deleted your question.  Anyway, the thing to remember is that the rank of a product of matrices is limited to the lowest rank in the product, but can be smaller.

Comment: If $B$ has rank $n-1$, then $UBU^T$ will have rank at most $n-1$, and so it can only be non-singular if $UBU^T$ has size at most $n-1$.

Comment: Sorry that I deleted it since I realized it later on about the issue you just mentioned. Thanks a lot for your comments, they are very helpful!